# Are word2vec embeddings the same if i re-train on the same sentences?

Tags: neural-network, nlp, word2vec

If I give the same sentences to a word2vec model and train it 2 different times (of course with the same vector size), do I obtain the same embeddings for words?

Answer (score 1):

There are several stochastic processes during word2vec training. First, the embeddings are randomly initialized, second, negative sampling is used to approximate the denominator in the softmax term. Only if those random processes, start with the same seed, the vectors will be exactly the same.

Otherwise, the training will converge to totally different vectors, however, the distances between the vectors will always be approximately the same.

Comment: Also, any use of multiple training threads – usually a big benefit for training speed – means the somewhat random/arbitrary influence of OS thread scheduling will slightly re-order training examples on each run. So even identically-seeded PRNGs won't ensure identical results. But each run (**if** there's appropriate data/parameters) should wind up with results that are *about as useful*, with words having *similar* (but not identical) ranked-lists of neighbors, even when the individual words wind up at very different coordinates.